# Creating multiple lessEntryPoints for custom error page in scala playframework 2.2.1

Tags: css, scala, less, playframework-2.2

I'm creating a custom error page for a website. For styling we use less. As it is now, the error page is using main.css. I would like it to use errorPages.css instead.

Doing research I found something and tried this...

```
def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
  (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "main.less") +++
  (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "errorPages.less")
)

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(customLessEntryPoints)
)
```

play -> play-less-entry-points lists what I expect it too. However, when I try to have the error page use errorPages.css instead, I get an error saying that the file errorPages.css is not found.

Perhaps I'm trying something that isn't possible. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I'm including errorPages.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/errorPages.css")>
```

This is in the Routes

```
GET /assets/*file   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: Could you show your code how you're including errorPages.css in the error page? And maybe even routes config.

Comment: What happens when you directly call :9000/assets/stylesheets/404.css?